# Not able to push files to remote Git repository

Tags: git, github

With this command:

```bash
$ git push -u ganesh master
```

I am getting this error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

I'm using Git Bash.  I'm able to commit files, but not able to push the files.  What could be the problem?

This is the output of the `$ git remote -v` command:

```
ganesh  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
ganesh  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)
ram     https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
ram     https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)
```

Comment: can you add the output of `git remote -v` in you question?

Comment: While i fire this command $ git remote -v  got this output.
    ganesh  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
    ganesh  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)
    origin  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)
    ram     https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (fetch)
    ram     https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git (push)

Comment: @GauravWagh you're using HTTPS to push to GitHub. Do you have a way to automatically enter your HTTPS username and password credentials? Did you have to enter them when you tried to push?

Comment: @GauravWagh by the way, I also notice that `ganesh` and `ram` both point to the same HTTPS url as `master`, is there a reason that those are duplicated like that? It's kind of an unusual setup, because you have 3 remote aliases all pointing to the same remote repo. I would think that you only needed `master`, unless those other aliases are supposed to point to different remote forks, in which case their urls are wrong, because they're both pointing to `https://github.com/Gauravwagh/hellow-dj.git `.

Comment: @GauravWagh There is a known bug around this in git 1.8.5. What's your git version? `git --version` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you configured git correctly, did you try removing the origin and adding it again?

Please try this:

`git remote rm origin
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'`

Comment: That will only work if he has the git repo configured to use SSH.

Comment: Then he should probably want to try with SSH.